# datatables: how to update a columns values from a row whose data-id=x

Tags: datatables

I use datatables jquery plugin.
I need to update colums values data from a row whose data-id is X
ex:

```js
<tr data-id="3415" role="row" class="even">
```

I dont' think I can just use jquery `$("tr[data-id=3415"]")`, but need to use

```js
var t = $('#tableQuiz').DataTable();
t.row....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery selectors on the dataTables API [**row()**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) method. Here an example adding "updated!" to all columns on the row with the `data-id` 3415 :

```js
var row = table.row('[data-id="3415"]'),
    data = row.data();

for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    data[i]=data[i]+' updated!';
}

row.data(data);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qpLav8a6/**

Comment: I've been looking for this. thank God found some valuable answer here. Thanks!